# Having trouble using pantheon-greeter-bzr and pantheon-session-bzr on virtualbox with ArchLinux

Tags: arch-linux, virtualbox, pacman, pantheon

I am trying to test ArchLinux with Pantheon on a VM on VirtualBox.
I am able to install ArchLinux and `pacman -S` the following packages succesfuly:

1. xorg-server
2. xorg-server-utils
3. virtualbox-guest-utils
4. pantheon-session-bzr
5. lightdm-pantheon-greeter-bzr

The next step I take is to edit my `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` to change my `greeter_session=` to `lightdm-pantheon-greeter`, but it is not working. This is what I get when I start lightdm:

[image]

This screen does not capture any input and after a while stops responding, and some elements are missing.

What am I doing wrong?

I do have 3D acceleration on in my VM settings.